# How to instruct GCC to stop after 5 errors?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Is it possible to instruct GNU c++ compiler to stop after 5 errors found? Can't find this in documentation.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The command-line option [`-fmax-errors=N`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) directs the compiler to give up after *N* errors.  This option is present in GCC 4.6 and later.

The command-line option [`-Wfatal-errors`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) directs the compiler to give up after *one* error.  This option is present in GCC 4.0 and later.

In both cases, warnings do not count toward the limit unless you also specify `-Werror`.

Comment: I'd give this +1 but for the statement about `-Werror`. I believe that warnings absolutely *should* be treated as if they were errors, because most warnings are an indication of buggy code.

Comment: @greyfade, I also think warnings should generally be treated as must-fix, but unfortunately some of gcc's warnings may trigger or not depending on optimization level, the contents of the system headers, and any number of other things you can't control easily.  Thus, you may get all the warnings out on your canonical build platform(s), but then some poor schmuck tries to build in a more exotic environment and it blows up.

Comment: @Zack, isn't that what -Wno-system-headers is for?

Comment: @Zack: I've never seen warnings triggered by optimizations, (could you cite examples?) and GCC, by default, suppresses warnings from headers marked as system headers (either by `#pragma` or with the `-isystem` switch). None of the things you mention have ever been a problem for me, and, in fact, `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` has identified and helped me fix more bugs than I can recount.

Comment: @greyfade: The most common problem people have is with `-Wuninitialized`, which may or may not be able to avoid false positives on conditional-set-conditional-use patterns that are obvious to a human, depending on the optimization level *and the target architecture*.  Which means you may not get warnings on x86 but someone who tries to build for ARM will.  Personally I prefer to add "unnecessary" initializations to squelch these, but some people argue _violently_ for not doing that.

Comment: @Zack: GCC *does* provide `-Wno-uninitialized` for cases where that's an issue, but I find it hard to believe that initializing variables is somehow a *bad* thing, even on ARM. (Although I will confess to not having built anything for ARM just yet.)

Comment: The arguments I've heard for not initializing variables that the compiler gets `-Wuninitialized` false positives on are: it wastes I-cache on dead-but-not-provably-dead store instructions; and if something changes that makes the warning a true positive, we want valgrind to catch it.

Comment: gcc can also generate spurious warnings on signed-overflow based on conditionals.  Usually it's the form of `if (a - b > c)` getting rearranged by the optimizer into `if (a > c + b)`.  That code is not wrong, but the optimizer warns when it rearranges things.

Comment: Unfortunately, linker doesn't honor `-fmax-errors` flag (as of arm-none-eabi-gcc 5.4.1). I was using option `-finstrument-functions` and I got hundreds of errors because of undefined `__cyg_profile_func_enter` function.

Comment: I find `-fmax-errors=1` to be more useful than `-Wfatal-errors` because the former shows details about the error while the latter doesn't give any infomation about the cause of the error.

Answer (score 52):

You can use gcc option:

```
-fmax-errors=5
```

for this purpose.

Comment: @Telthien Why? This seems like an answer to me.

Comment: @Telthien http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer says "any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" and "brevity is acceptable". Answers are designed to provide a solution, sometimes that can be accomplished in a single sentence.

Comment: if it is useful as short then there is no reason to lengthen the answer. Especially not for the sake of being overlengthy or asking-for-tldr.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware that a new feature had been added since I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would welcome such an option as well. For now, I'm using the following workaround to get the first five errors:

```
<make> 2>&1|grep error|head -5
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to ask why you would want to do this.  Sometimes the error that exists in the code is not the first or even found in the first five errors.  Sometimes it's beyond that and only is recognizable once you scroll down the list.  A better method might be to break up your code and place it into smaller libraries if you're bothered by compile times.  Or if you're concerned with things scrolling off the screen of a command line, using the '>>' operator to pipe the messages into a file.

Comment: It's just a matter of error log readability. 5 errors are more than enough to understand the problem, at least in my case :)

Comment: Really?  My experience has been just the opposite -- especially in C++, unless I'm doing specific sorts of refactoring work that create lots of discrete errors (changing the arguments to a commonly-used method, e.g.)  the very first error is likely to be the only one that's any use at all.

Comment: @FaZend.com I see, I'm sorry I provided a non-answer then.  Zack's answer below is probably the best you're going to get to unless you're going to write a small script to parse these error and kill the process after 5 errors are output.  (although I might be quite ignorant in this statement.)

Comment: Nevertheless, your output redirection answer is not bad.  Combine it with e.g. the `head` utility and you can limit the amount of error messages.  But note that tail measures in lines, and some error messages take more than one line.

Comment: People seem to have very limited imagination on this issue. What about this scenario? You've just ported a program to a new environment for the first time. You get a couple of errors and the compilation aborts. You have no idea how many incompatibilities there are between the old environment and the new one. What you want to know is how bad the situation is and how many issues there are in your code. You'd like to get all the errors in one huge list so you can estimate how long it will take you to fix them all.

Comment: @PhillApley The problem with that is that a single error often sets off a cascade of flow-on errors (some with tons of STL suggestions), so if you judge by the volume of errors and warnings, you might overestimate the effort needed and give up.