# List only files where compilation errors happened

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, emacs, compilation

I want a list of files where compilation errors happened without duplicates. Like so:

```
/home/luizromario/project/src/foo.cpp
/home/luizromario/project/src/bar.cpp
```

I'm using Emacs's compilation mode to run gcc. Is there some way to achieve that either through gcc itself or through Emacs?

---

Edit: I'm running `make` with the `-k0` option, so the compilation process already keeps going as long as it can. My goal is to create a list of files I need to go through to make some small adjustments so that the compilation succeeds. I already know what the compilation error is (I marked one specific method as `[[deprecated]]`), so I don't need any diagnostics.

Comment: Just the files as in you do not yet care what and where in the file the errors are?

Comment: One classic issue is that many of the errors may be false positives.  For example, you fix the first error and many of the following disappear.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223732/how-to-instruct-gcc-to-stop-after-5-errors) help?

Comment: @user4581301 Something along these lines, yes

Comment: @NathanPierson I am not sure how that would help me

Comment: There might be some ideas in this old question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11313600/315052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for some ideas[1](https://serverfault.com/questions/398187/how-to-delete-all-characters-in-one-line-after-with-sed), here's what I found works for me:

```
more compilation-out | grep "error:" | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq
```

(There are several options to do this on Emacs[2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68636/filter-text-of-buffer-in-a-grep-like-way/)).